# How to deal with all the Observables when building an Angular App that uses Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, combinelatest

I've built a few apps with Angular and Firebase and I'm just starting a new one.  I'm interested in how others deal with getting data using observables.  In my specific app I need to use an observable to get the parameters from the URL, check if the user is authenticated, and get 2 different objects from firebase.  I need to first check auth, then get parameters from the URL so I can find the locations of the firebase objects.  In the past I've just done a nest of observable subscriptions like this.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
      if (auth) {
        this.uid = auth.uid;
        this.af.database.list('objectives', {
          query: {
            orderByChild: 'AuthorID',
            equalTo: auth.uid
          }
        }).subscribe(objectives => {
          console.log(objectives);
          this.allObjectives = objectives;
        })
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['login'])
      }
    })
  }
```

Now I have to add the parameters and another call to firebase.  I've tried using rxjs's combineLatest but it doesn't look like I can use data returned from one observable to use in another.  My question is, has anyone solved a similar issue without nesting subscriptions?

Below is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "wdw-hunt",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "hammer-timejs": "^1.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.4.2",
    "ng2-simple-page-scroll": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "firebase-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

Below is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it

Guard:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {AngularFire} from 'angularfire2';
import {isNullOrUndefined} from 'util';

@Injectable()
export class OverviewGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {

  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.af.auth.map(auth => {
      if (isNullOrUndefined(auth)) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Some provider:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire} from 'angularfire2';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

  @Injectable()
  export class JobProvider {
    constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
    }

    public getSomething(): Observable<Something> {
      return this.getUserDb()
        .switchMap(path => this.af.database.object(`${path}/something`));
    }

    private getUserDb(): Observable<string> {
      return this.af.auth
        .map(auth => `/debug/users/${auth.uid}`);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks!  This looks very promising, I'll try it out!

Comment: When I try to use map on this.af.auth I get a ts error that says:  [ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
(property) AngularFire.auth: AngularFireAuth

Comment: are you using the lastest version of AngularFire2 and Firebase?

Comment: I'm using angularfire2 2.0.0-beta.7-pre and firebase 3.9.0

Comment: I used  angularfire2 2.0.0-beta.8 and I saw some auth  breaking change there. I think you should give it a try

Comment: Tried that but still no luck.  Maybe there's a conflict with an installed library.  In the above are you importing rxjs/add/operator/map?

Comment: No i'm not. I added my imports for you

Comment: Thanks again Robin!  Is it possible there is an issue with my ts-config? or maybe vscode?

Comment: It might me you rxjs version. I'm using 5.1.0. But it might also be vscode which is complaining about nothing. Have you tried actually running it?

Comment: I have tried running it but I get a compiler error.  I've added my package.json and tsconfig.  I'll look into how to ignoring the compiler errors and running.

Comment: Stick to angularfire 2.0.0-beta.8 for now. I saw another breaking change. remove the `^`

Comment: I reinstalled VS code and now everything seems to work fine!